# Flash taskbar icon in RemoteApp application

Tags: c#, taskbar, remoteapp

I have an application written in c# where I was able to get it to flash the taskbar icon using FlashWindowEx. However, this application also gets used as a RemoteApp using RDP. When in RemoteApp mode the taskbar does not flash. I found an article from 2012 that said that you cannot get the taskbar to flash in a RemoteApp.

Has anyone been able to successfully flash the icon in the taskbar for a RemoteApp? If not, any suggestions on other options available to call a user's attention that they have new notifications to read?

Here is the article that I am referencing: http://www.daveamenta.com/2012-11/using-remoteapps-on-surface-rt-windows-rt/

In particular:
"IM apps like Digsby work well, but the taskbar “needy state” (flashing) does not translate to the remote session. Jumplists and taskbar thumbnail controls also don’t translate over."

Comment: We have the same problem in a Citrix virtualization environment, which is not exactly RDP, but maybe the same kind of restriction applies. Would you mind linking that article you mentioned, or at least add a citation of the relevant parts to your post?

Comment: Updated my post to reference the article and citation.